# Sending an event and setting a value externally in Svelte?

Tags: javascript, svelte

I am trying to both forward an event and let a value be set externally using Svelte. If a button is clicked, the greeting should have from "Hello" to "Goodbye".

App.Svelte

```js
<script>
  import Component from "./Component.svelte";
  const handleMessage = (event, greeting) => {
    if (greeting === "hello") {
      greeting = "goodbye";
    } else {
      greeting = "hello";
    }
  };
</script>

<main>
    <Component on:message={handleMessage}/>
</main>
```

Component.Svelte

```js
<script>
  import { createEventDispatcher } from "svelte";
  const dispatch = createEventDispatcher();
  export let name = "Friend";
  export let greeting = "hello";

  const func = () => {
    dispatch("message", {});
  };
</script>

<p> {greeting}, {name} </p>
<button on:click={dispatch}> switch greeting</button>
```

However, whenever I click the button, the desired effect is not achieved. What needs to happen such that clicking a button on the nested component (Component) changes the greeting?

Comment: Are you looking to solve this in the best way or by using `dispatch`? The reason I ask is that it would be a lot more straightforward to do this by passing a click handler up from the child to the parent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the component hierarchy is as you describe, I wouldn't use `dispatch` for this. I would pass a click handler to the child component.

Relevant tutorial doc: https://svelte.dev/tutorial/dom-event-forwarding

**App.svelte**

```html
<script>
  import Component from "./Component.svelte";
  let greeting = "hello"
    let name = "world"
    const onClick = () => {
      if (greeting === "hello") {
        greeting = "goodbye";
      } else {
        greeting = "hello";
      }
    }
</script>

<main>
    <Component on:click={onClick} {greeting} {name}/>
</main>
```

**Component.svelte**

```html
<script>
  export let greeting;
  export let name;
</script>

<p> {greeting}, {name} </p>
<button on:click> switch greeting</button>
```

---

#### If you really wanted to use `dispatch`:

**App.svelte**

```html
<script>
  import Component from "./Component.svelte";
  let greeting = "hello"
  let name = "world"
  function handleMessage(e) {
    if (e.detail.name !== "updateGreeting") return;
    if (greeting === "hello") {
      greeting = "goodbye";
    } else {
      greeting = "hello";
    }
  }
</script>

<main>
    <Component on:message={handleMessage} {greeting} {name}/>
</main>
```

**Component.svelte**

```html
<script>
    import {createEventDispatcher} from "svelte";
    export let greeting;
    export let name;
    const dispatch = createEventDispatcher();
    const click = () => {
        dispatch("message", {name: "updateGreeting"});
    }
</script>

<p> {greeting}, {name} </p>
<button on:click={click}> switch greeting</button>
```

Comment: you can just forward the on:click `<Component on:click={onClick} {greeting} {name}/>` and then `<button on:click> switch greeting</button>`

Comment: I agree that forwarding the message is cleaner. For my understanding, does forwarding only work top-down one level? (In other words, this design wouldn't work if either 1/ there was an additional nested component between App and Component or 2/ the flow needed to be reversed, upward from Component to App?)

Comment: Also, do you need `{name: "updateGreeting"}` in the dispatched message or the related `if` statement in App?

Comment: @jbuddy_13 I believe you can forward dom event handlers with additional nested components. Although in those situations I might pass it as a prop, but that is personal preference. I always use names when dispatching messages, but I reckon if you are only sending one message, ever, you could omit it